# PIL and Pillow Installer Closes Abruptly Without Installing (Windows 10)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I'm running Python 2.7.15 on my 64 bit Windows computer. I have tried numerous times to download the 64 bit versions of PIL and Pillow on my laptop (.exe installer versions). But every single time, I click Install and the installer waits a few seconds before closing abruptly without installing. I checked that both my system and python are both 64 bit. I even tried installing the 32 bit PIL and Pillow on my computer but I got the same results: doesn't install and closes abruptly. Does anyone have the 64 bit files of PIL or Pillow for Python 2.7 that I can directly import into my python site packages folder? Also, what is the problem here? I tried shutting down and restarting but nothing seems to help. Thanks.

Comment: Download VirtualBox and run any Linux OS of your choice. It will spare you many future problems with developing python on Windows, trust me.

Comment: By the way, have you tried to install it with [windows pip](https://matthewhorne.me/how-to-install-python-and-pip-on-windows-10/)?

Comment: Did you update your path?

Comment: @RaoslawSzamszur Or use Bash on Ubuntu on Windows...if using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Although I still do not know why my computer is not installing PIL or Pillow, I installed Pillow on another computer and downloaded the files onto a USB, which I then transfered into my Python folder.  This works perfectly and I now have all the Pillow files on my computer.